# Can I redirect all web requests from Android through a proxy server?

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, proxy-server

I'm trying to set up the proxy server in Android, where every web request should be first sent to the proxy server, which then decides whether to send the original page or a page optimized for faster mobile downloads. 
I looked into mirrorrr, which seems to be a proxy server on the App Engine. If I go to https://mirrorrr.appspot.com/techcrunch.com the page loads, but if I set the Chrome proxy server settings to https://mirrorrr.appspot.com, and then go to techcrunch.com, then no webpage loads.

How can I get every single web page to redirect to my app domain (example.com), so I can take action on my server and send a more optimized page (compression etc)? I think this should be a solved problem, so looking for a possible plug-and-play open source solution.

Thanks!

Comment: System wide network redirection isn't allowed on Android (at least without root access).

Comment: This is more of an android issue than a GAE one, consider changing tags to get better results. Having said that, you are hoping to find a way to hijack every single request and send it through a 3rd party page first, my guess is there are several systems in place to prevent developers from doing this for obvious security reasons. As stated by @AdvaitS at the least you are going to need a rooted device to get access to the OS routing table.

Comment: Isn't that what this app does: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.proxyserver&hl=en ?
Also, read some articles that seemed to be able to achieve this: http://www.techverse.net/how-to-setup-proxy-server-3g-4g-data-connection-android-phone/ , so was wondering what I'm missing?

Comment: Btw, I have the same issue when I'm trying to redirect it from my Desktop Chrome, so its not about Android, it about the proxy: mirrorrr.com/techcrunch.com loads fine, but techcrunch.com does not. And since mirrorrr is meant to be an App Engine web proxy, I didn't include Android tag in the qn. Currently I'm trying to debug why the proxy server isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Also, internet.org seems to already be able to do this: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2015/05/internetorg-not-neutral-not-secure-and-not-internet
"make the site available for Internet.org users to access for free, by routing the communication through the Internet.org proxy server. That proxy server allows the sites to be “zero rated” by participating mobile phone operators; allows the automatic stripping out of content that violates the guidelines—such as images greater than 1Mb in size, videos, VoIP calls, Flash and Java applets and even JavaScript"